# How to check if construction of a new codecvt_byname succeeded

Tags: c++, localization, codecvt

Is there a standard way to check whether construction of a new `std::codecvt_byname` succeeded?

I was experimenting with the following program:

```
// cl /nologo /Fetest_codecvt_byname.exe /EHsc test_codecvt_byname.cpp && test_codecvt_byname
// g++ -o test_codecvt_byname test_codecvt_byname.cpp && test_codecvt_byname

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <new>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    try {
        new std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>(".nonsense");
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

libstdc++ on Windows apparently throws a `std::runtime_error` object if the named locale is unsupported. Microsoft Visual C++'s STL implementation, however, does not throw an exception.

Not knowing which C++ compiler will compile the code, how do I check whether construction of the new `std::codecvt_byname` succeeded? Alternatively, is there a way to check whether construction will be successful assuming no out-of-memory scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section [22.3.1.1.2], Class `locale::facet`, of the C++11 FDIS states:

> For some standard facets a standard "...`_byname`" class, derived from it, implements the virtual function semantics equivalent to that facet of the locale constructed by `locale(const char*)` with the same name.

The Standard unfortunately does not require an exception to be thrown by the `std::codecvt_byname` constructor if the named locale is invalid, as does the explicit `std::locale` constructor `locale(const char*)`. However, a work-around is to attempt to construct the locale and [`use_facet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt587566.aspx) the `codecvt` facet instead of attempting to use `std::codecvt_byname`.